# insert a dataframe to every row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

But can someone help me out there? That would be great.

I have a data frame like this:

```
  Date        Day      Month            
   0    2020-01-01  Wednesday   1
   1    2020-01-02  Thursday    1
   2    2020-01-03  Friday  1
   5    2020-01-06  Monday  1
   6    2020-01-07  Tuesday 1
```

and another dataset looks like :

```
   [W]  Gewerbe     Werktag
   0    00:00:00    255.9
   1    01:00:00    216.6
   2    02:00:00    196.3
   3    03:00:00    194.5
   4    04:00:00    226.8
```

And I want to merge them either like this :

```
  Date        Day      Month            Gewerbe
   0    2020-01-01  Wednesday   1       00:00:00    255.9
                                        01:00:00    216.6
                                        02:00:00    196.3
                                        03:00:00    194.5
                                        04:00:00    226.8
   ......................................................
```

or this

```
  Date        Day      Month            Gewerbe
   0    2020-01-01  Wednesday   1       00:00:00    255.9
   0    2020-01-01  Wednesday   1       01:00:00    216.6
   0    2020-01-01  Wednesday   1       02:00:00    196.3
   0    2020-01-01  Wednesday   1       03:00:00    194.5
   0    2020-01-01  Wednesday   1       04:00:00    226.8
   1    2020-01-02  Thursday    1       00:00:00    255.9
   1    2020-01-02  Thursday    1       01:00:00    216.6
   1    2020-01-02  Thursday    1       02:00:00    196.3
   1    2020-01-02  Thursday    1       03:00:00    194.5
   1    2020-01-02  Thursday    1       04:00:00    226.8
   .......and so on.....
```

Any idea how to solve this ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are there any columns that link the dataframes? Or could you explain where the link between the tables are?

Comment: Hi, There are actually no link between the tables. so every row will get all the data from the second dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cross merge like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{"index": 0, "Date": "2020-01-01", "Day": "Wednesday", "Month": 1}, 
{"index": 1, "Date": "2020-01-02", "Day": "Thursday", "Month": 1},
{"index": 2, "Date": "2020-01-03", "Day": "Friday", "Month": 1},
{"index": 5, "Date": "2020-01-06", "Day": "Monday", "Month": 1},
{"index": 6, "Date": "2020-01-07", "Day": "Tuesday", "Month": 1}]


data2= [{"Gewerbe": "00:00:00 ", "Werktag": "255.9"},
        {"Gewerbe": "01:00:00 ", "Werktag": "216.6"},
        {"Gewerbe": "02:00:00 ", "Werktag": "196.3"},
        {"Gewerbe": "03:00:00 ", "Werktag": "194.5"},
        {"Gewerbe": "04:00:00 ", "Werktag": "226.8"}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df = df.set_index('index')


new_dataframe = pd.merge(df, df2, how="cross")
```

Comment: thanks for your help. it seems right. but one problem . newdataframe should consist every row with the complete 2nd data frame. Like for the Thursday, Friday and so on...

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look. @revalerstrasse

Comment: Oh okay, then I think just swap out the new_datframe line I have in the original version with this:
```new_dataframe = pd.merge(df, df2, how="cross")```